# iOS distribute application using another account

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I am distributing an `iOS` application using my developer account (this is for testing purposes). Now i want to use another account and distribute the application.  Questions are as follows:

1.) Am i permitted to do so? If not what is the solution?

2.) Can i change the `application ID` (`appId`) `apple` provides?

3.) Will deleting the application from the developer portal help?

I tried googling for possible solution, but was unable to find anything that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an app with the same bundle ID on two accounts.  However, with the new version of iTunes Connect you now have the ability to transfer an app to another account.  After that you won't be able to distribute it using the first account anymore.  There is a lot of preparation that you need to do and it will take a while, but the details are in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html) (Managing Your Applications -> Transferring Your App).

Comment: Can't i register a new app under a different account, and add devices and generate a new distribution profile. Then add it to code sign etc? Will that work?

Comment: As long as it is a different bundle ID, and you haven't put it on the app store using the first one, yes.

Comment: No haven't put it on appstore, but have added as `distribution`. And how can i change the bundle ID?

Comment: I leave that as an exercise for you.  It's not too hard to figure out, but a pain to explain in a comment.  It's that thing that looks like "com.yourcompany.yourappname" when you look at the app settings in Xcode